# Implementation of many-to-many relation Tag Table

Tags: c#, mvc, entity-framework

I have belowe tables, for Map `string[] Tags` from `ViewModel` to `Model` I'm using Below codes :

```
  public class Tag:BaseEntity
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Blog.BlogPost> BlogPosts { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<News.NewsItem> NewsItems { get; set; }

}
 public class BlogPost : BaseContent, IAuditable
    {
    public virtual ICollection<Tag> Tags { get; set; }
}


public class NewsItem : BaseContent, IAuditable
    {
    public virtual ICollection<Tag> Tags { get; set; }

    public NewsItem()
    {
        Tags = new List<Tag>();
    }
}
```

In newsService I have two methods `Insert ,Update` to Add and Update NewsItem :

```
     public void Insert(AddNewsItemViewModel newsItemViewModel)
    {
        if (newsItemViewModel == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("newsItem");

        var model = Mapper.Map<NewsItem>(newsItemViewModel);

        if(newsItemViewModel.Tags.Any()) // Tags is `string[]`
        {
            var listOfActualTags = _tagService.GetTagsByName(newsItemViewModel.Tags); // return List<Tag> 
            var listOfActualTagNames = listOfActualTags.Select(x => x.Name.ToLower()).ToList();

            foreach (var tag in newsItemViewModel.Tags)
            {
                if (!listOfActualTagNames.Contains(tag.ToLowerInvariant().Trim()))
                {
                    Tag tagModel = new Tag { Name=tag};
                    _tagService.Insert(tagModel);
                    model.Tags.Add(tagModel);
                }
            }

            model.MetaKeywords =string.Join(",",newsItemViewModel.Tags);
        }
        _uow.MarkAsAdded(model);
    }
```

and for `Update`  Method I have this Code :

```
        public void Update(EditNewsItemViewModel newsItemViewModel)
    {
        if (newsItemViewModel == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("newsItem");
        var model = GetById(newsItemViewModel.Id);
        model = Mapper.Map(newsItemViewModel, model);
        if (model.Tags != null && model.Tags.Any())
            model.Tags.Clear();

        var listOfActualTags = _tagService.GetTagsByName(newsItemViewModel.Tags); // return List<Tag>
        var listOfActualTagNames = listOfActualTags.Select(x => x.Name.ToLower()).ToList();

        foreach (var tag in newsItemViewModel.Tags)
        {
            Tag tagModel = new Tag { Name = tag };
            if (!listOfActualTagNames.Contains(tag.ToLowerInvariant().Trim()))
            {

                _tagService.Insert(tagModel);
                model.Tags.Add(tagModel);
            }
            else
                model.Tags.Add(tagModel);
        }

        model.MetaKeywords = string.Join(",", newsItemViewModel.Tags);

        _uow.MarkAsChanged(model);
    }
```

For `BlogPost` I have to repeat Above Code (for tag part) fro that , Is there a way to Optimize this ?

Comment: `Mapper.Map<NewsItem>(newsItemViewModel);` why are you mapping all models instead of simply showing what you have? Without mapping you could just save the updated data instead of translating it each time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `Insert` method has a bug - if a tag exists in a database, you won't add it to your `model.Tags` collection. Interesting enough, your `Update` method doesn't have that problem. After you fix that bug, you're left with almost identical part of the code that could also be reused by `BlogPost` logic.

Because it should be reused, it would be best to place it in your `TagService` and, after a few improvements, it would look like this:

```
public void AddTagsToList(ICollection<Tag> tagList, string[] tagNames)
{
  var listOfActualTags = GetTagsByName(tagNames);

  foreach (var tagName in tagNames)
  {
    var tag = listOfActualTags.FirstOrDefault(t => t.Name == tagName);

    if (tag == null)
    {
      tag = new Tag { Name = tagName };
      Insert(tag);
    }

    tagList.Add(tag);
  }
}
```

Your `Insert` method would become:

```
public void Insert(AddNewsItemViewModel newsItemViewModel)
{
  if (newsItemViewModel == null)
    throw new ArgumentNullException("newsItem");

  var model = Mapper.Map<NewsItem>(newsItemViewModel);

  if(newsItemViewModel.Tags.Any())
  {
    _tagService.AddTagsToList(model.Tags, newsItemViewModel.Tags);

    model.MetaKeywords = string.Join(",", newsItemViewModel.Tags);
  }

  _uow.MarkAsAdded(model);
}
```

And `Update` method would become:

```
public void Update(EditNewsItemViewModel newsItemViewModel)
{
  if (newsItemViewModel == null)
      throw new ArgumentNullException("newsItem");
  var model = GetById(newsItemViewModel.Id);
  model = Mapper.Map(newsItemViewModel, model);
  if (model.Tags != null && model.Tags.Any())
    model.Tags.Clear();

  if(newsItemViewModel.Tags.Any())
  {
    _tagService.AddTagsToList(model.Tags, newsItemViewModel.Tags);

    model.MetaKeywords = string.Join(",", newsItemViewModel.Tags);
  }

  _uow.MarkAsChanged(model);
}
```

As I said, you can reuse `_tagService.AddTagsToList` method for `BlogPost` as well by providing the `Tags` property as a first parameter and a list of tag names as a second parameter.

Answer (score 2):

> ```
>  if (!listOfActualTagNames.Contains(tag.ToLowerInvariant().Trim()))
>         {
>
>             _tagService.Insert(tagModel);
>             model.Tags.Add(tagModel);
>         }
>         else
>             model.Tags.Add(tagModel);
> ```

Can be changed to

```
 if (!listOfActualTagNames.Contains(tag.ToLowerInvariant().Trim()))
            _tagService.Insert(tagModel);

model.Tags.Add(tagModel);
```